# Changed to CPF instead of email on login page. Now what?

Tags: laravel, authentication

CPF is a Brazilian code like US Social Secure Number.
I´ve changed my login page to it and it is working fine. The trick now is the following:

Clients and employers will use the same login page with different roles. So far, so good.
The matter is that employers are on the database and clients I need to search via WS, a task that I am already doing ok.

So I need to check if the login user is an employer and send him to his home, or if he is a client, how do I send him to the SoapController to make the call to the WS? I can´t figure where is the "query" to the 'users' table.

In time: A client for me, is a user with a different role, so I put them all on the same data table.

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution:

At the LoginController I wrote a new login function that had subscribed Laravel´s original login.

Let´s see some code:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'cpfCnpj';
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
    $login = $credentials[$this->username()];
    if (User::where($this->username(), $login)->count() > 0) {
        return 'Login exists';
    } else {
        return 'vai pro SoapController';
    }
}
```

Now I can check on another database and then do whatever I need with the answer.
Hope this can help who needs!